# How to restore log-out screen using terminal

Tags: 14.04, restore, reset

I'm new on Ubuntu and trying to learn more. I changed to a Mac theme, but now I'm trying to restore the default theme. I've manged to do everything except change the login screen but cannot; I've tried everything. 
If anyone could help me solve this problem using the terminal that would be great.

Comment: Which mac theme did you install?

Comment: ww.noobslab.com/2014/04/macbuntu-1404-pack-is-released.html        thats the tutorial

Comment: You mean the screen where you login right?

Comment: yes thats the one the way to see it is to log out, where u have to out ur pasword

Comment: Enter the command given in the answer and reboot.

Comment: ok thanks alot im new on linux and i really need help  thanks

Answer (score 1):

Enter the following into a terminal

`sudo apt-get remove mbuntu-lightdm-v3`